# Biprefix code and word factorization

Tags: abstract-algebra, information-theory, coding-theory, monoid

Let $Y_1$ a biprefix code over a free monoid $A^{*}$. Let $u= x_{i}y_{j}$ and $v= x_{i}’y_{j}’$, with $x_i, x_i’ \in A^*$ and $y_j, y_j’ \in Y_1$.  If $u=v$, while does this imply that $y_{i} = y_{i}’$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A biprefix code is in particular a suffix code. Now $u = v$ implies that either $y_j$ is a suffix of $y'_j$ or that $y_j$ is a suffix of $y'_j$. Since your code is suffix, this implies $y_j = y'_j$.

EDIT (Answer to your comment). Would this picture help you?

[image: Suffix]

Comment: Thank you :) I still don’t understand why $u=v$ implies that $y_j$ is a suffix of $y_j’$ or viceversa, though. Could you please give me some more detail about this?

Comment: Yes, now I see it. Thank you!